# inspecting android sqlite and IntelliJ

Tags: android, sqlite, intellij-idea, adb

I'm starting out with a small app using programmatically created sqlite db.
Is there a way to inspect that db when the app is running on emulator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download the database file from the device to your PC and then use any SQLite browser / tool to inspect the database.

Either via the `adb` commandline tool from the Android SDK tools

```
adb pull /data/data/your.app.package.here/databases/yourdatabasefile.db
```

or via the device browser (File Explorer) in Eclipse in the DDMS perpective (maybe that exists in IntelliJ too, Idk)

or the new Android SDK tools provide a neat standalone version of that DDMS perspective & the file explorer via the new Device Monitor tool (`android-sdk/tools/monitor.bat`)

Comment: Consider voting for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67759 so that it works automatically.

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible with IntelliJ IDEA 14:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/accessing-android-sqlite-databases-from-intellij-idea.html

Comment: I have intellij 14.1.1 but I haven't the window Database under tool windows in view menu. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: @LeiNaD_87 you need to activate the "Database Tools and SQL" plugin from Settings

Comment: Im on Android Studio 1.2.2 and can't find the plugin
http://i.imgur.com/OjNWOaP.png

Comment: It's an Ultimate edition feature only, not available in Android Studio: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/database_tools.html

Answer (score 0):

A partner found a more dynamic solution, using an ADB plug-in you can simply choose the database and refresh the inspector any time you want

first, you need to download the plug in jar
https://github.com/tklerx/android-sqlite-browser-for-eclipse
(go to releases and choose the latest)

then place the jar into [YourAndroidSdkDirectory]/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/plugins/

Restart ADB

Done! now run an emulator, create your database and browse in the ADB to find it on data/data/ ...
Select it and click new the Database buton up right
(you may not see the button before selecting the database file)

[image: Preview]

Source:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/Jqw9VslC_Vw/YOXWQa1ozmAJ